# Input Validation of a Floating Point Number (Inside a Try-Catch Block)

Tags: java, try-catch, validation

I've tried scouring Google and several sites such as this to find an answer to my question and I'm just not having any luck. I'm in a second-tier Java course in college, and I'm trying to figure out how to do input validation on a floating point number while using a try-catch block. The gist of the scenario is as such:

A driver will call the method promptForMotherHeight(), this method is supposed to pull in a user's entry as a floating point number. The issue is that with the try-catch block, if the Scanner detects a non-floating point number, it won't dump the data out of the scanner's buffer. This leads to an infinite loop. I've tinkered with adding a Scanner.next() inside my catch block, but any data entered after the first attempt will not validate properly (meaning that I can enter in something such as 5.55555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555 and it will accept this as a valid input).

Here's what I'm working with, code-wise (I've imported all the things I need to at the top of the class and motherHeight is a private float instance variable at the top of the class):

```
public void promptForMotherHeight()
{    
    String motherHeightPrompt = "Enter mother's height in inches: ";
    String motherError1 = "Invalid entry. Must be positive.";
    String motherError2 = "Invalid entry. Must be a decimal number.";    
    boolean valid = false;

    do
    {
        System.out.print(motherHeightPrompt);
        try 
        {
            motherHeight = stdIn.nextFloat(); 
            valid = true;
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e)
        {
            System.out.println(motherError2);
            stdIn.next();        
        }
    } while(!valid);
}
```

Any pointers or hints as to how I can accomplish proper input validation would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: That looks like a valid float to me.

Comment: Oh....? Erm... what would be an invalid float then.
3.4028235E38 is what java lists as the max.... doesn't that mean 38 more digit places? Or am I just really out of it right now?

Comment: remove `stdIn.next();` in the catch block.

Comment: Gnomez, as I said in my write-up, if you do that it kicks you into an infinite loop after one incorrect input because the scanner's buffer won't clear in a try-catch

Comment: then your code runs well. No changes needed.

Comment: @ZachFiedler : It's not *decimal* places. It's base E. Exponential.
plus, your code works for 3.4028235E38 too..

Comment: Ahhhhh that makes much more sense. Thank you very much for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the floating point number validation in the `try-catch` like this.

```
do {
    System.out.print(motherHeightPrompt);
    try {
        motherHeight = Float.parseFloat(stdIn.nextLine()); // This will read the line and try to parse it to a floating value
        valid = true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) { // if it was not a valid float, you'll get this exception
        System.out.println(motherError2);
            // You need not have that extra stdIn.next()
            // it loops again, prompting the user for another input
    }
} while (!valid); // The loop ends when a valid float is got from the user
```

Comment: This one was a while back, but I was able to plug it in to my old solution and get a working feature. If I remember correctly, we were required to used the InputMismatchException, but this looks like a better answer to keep in mind for the ol' knowledge vault :)!